# Apply transformation of group to each element

Tags: svg.js

I'm using svg.js to some seat manipulations and I hit the wall with rotating a group.
I want to transfer the group's rotation to the elements in that group, that way I can save every element as one row in the database.

Here is the example on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/426134/

```
drawing = new SVG('drawing').size('100%', '100%');
var circle1 = rawing.circle().radius(25).fill('#ff0000').cx(30).cy(30);
var circle2 = drawing.circle().radius(25).fill('#ff0000').cx(70).cy(70);
group = drawing.group();
group.add(circle1);
group.add(circle2);
group.rotate(20);
```

In the example I'm creating two circles adding them to group and rotating the group. Now the group has the attribute: `transform="matrix(0.9396926207859084,0.3420201433256687,-0.3420201433256687,0.9396926207859084,20.116376126988012,-14.08563820557886)"`

Is it possible to ungroup and apply the transformation to each element of the group this way preserving the positions and rotations that happened while elements were in the group?

Comment: You want to `ungroup()` the group

Comment: Thanks @Fuzzyma that works as I asked for it, but it raises a lot more problems unfortunately. I'm using svg.select.js and selecting my elements with collision detection described here: https://yal.cc/rectangle-circle-intersection-test/ after transformations that selection is not working. Now i have to rewrite the selection algorithm but I don't know how :(